# Error installing caffe due to boost-python

Tags: boost, cmake, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to install pycaffe, but am failing the command `make pycaffe` with the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lboost_python
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
```

I installed `boost-python` with the command `brew install --build-from-source -vd boost boost-python`. In my `/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python` folder, I have v1.67 with files `libboost_python27.dylib` and `libboost_python27-mt.dylib`, as well as their respective `.a` files.

Since caffe is looking for `lboost_python` and not `libboost_python`, should I just simlink one to the other? How would I go about this?

Comment: `-lboost_python` resolves to search for a library called `libboost_python`, so this part is fine. However, you should have a library called libboost_python.* .I'm not sure about the correct file ending on mac (therefore a comment, not an answer), the important part is that it must not include a version number or you need to adapt your Makefile to use `-lboost_python27`. You can also symlink `libboost_python27.dylib` to `libboost_python.dylib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python3

```
brew install boost --with-python3
brew install boost-python
```

Confirm boost and boost-python is installed

```
    brew list | grep 'boost'
```

Then create symlink

```
 Example : sudo ln -s libboost_python37.dylib libboost_python3.dylib
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: Hi I am having similar issue when running 'make all' command while compiling caffe: I get error: ld: library not found for -lboost_python3 I tried your suggestion brew list | grep 'boost' it lists boost, boost-python and boost-python3. Then I tried the sudo command, it accepted it without any output. The make all still gives the same error however. Could you please let me know what I can do to resolve this?